# Is $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm{sgn}(\cos mx\cos nx)\sqrt{|\cos mx\cos nx|}dx=0$ correct?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

When studying Fourier analysis, I wonder if $\cos\bot\sin$ under $\|\cdot\|_1$ or sth. likewise, and this is the question:

Whether $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathop{\mathrm{sgn}}(\cos mx\cos nx)\sqrt{|\cos mx\cos nx|}~\mathrm{d} x=0$.

$m\neq n$ are integers. When $\frac{m}{2p+1}=\frac{n}{2q+1}=2^t,p,q\in\mathbb N$, it is hard to use the symmetry of trigonometric functions.

Comment: the part in the square root can be negative

Comment: What about this notation? It's much clearer because you clearly see the end of the root: $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \mathop{\mathrm{sign}}(\cos (mx) \cdot \cos (nx)) \cdot \sqrt{\cos (mx) \cdot \cos (nx)}~\mathrm{d}x$$.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have made some edits.

Comment: Here this strange $\mathrm{sgn}\sqrt(x)$ is the square root that keep the sign of x

Comment: What does $\frac{m}{2p+1}=\frac{n}{2q+1}=2^t$ have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not.

Consider $m=1,n=3$. It is about -0.57634726 (using MATLAB..).

I'm an idiot.

Comment: Is it $\frac{\pi}{2}$ by any chance?

Comment: @dylan-levine I suppose not
Using ```f=@(m,n)integral(@(x)sqrt(abs(cos(m*x).*cos(n*x))).*sign(cos(m*x).*cos(n*x)),-pi,pi)```
There isn't a result greater than $\frac\pi2$